# Choosing an appropriate statistical model, must I use linear mixed model, or will a general linear model suffice?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

`enter code here`My issue is related to model choice. I have a data set containing day path length (DPL) and a bunch of different behaviours of a lemur species collected in the field via instantaneous fields scans. I hoped to investigate DPL using the following predictors: site (fragmented or continuous forest), group, feeding, resting, socialising and locomotion time as a proportion of each focal day per group.

I first ran a simple general linear model using all of my predictors and subsequently used stepwise selection and AIC value criteria to select the most suitable model (Group, feeding time and resting time all came out as significant predictors).. 
However I was then convinced I should run a linear mixed model, with group nested in habitat to allow for the non-independence in the data. My final lme did not give me any significant results..

My Outputs:

```
Start:  AIC=282.12
DPL ~ Group + Habitat + Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans... + 
    Locomotion..scans... + Socialising..scans... + Day.Length


Step:  AIC=282.12
DPL ~ Group + Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans... + Locomotion..scans... + 
    Socialising..scans... + Day.Length

                        Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
- Socialising..scans...  1      2200 189161 280.48
- Day.Length             1      4166 191126 280.79
- Locomotion..scans...   1      6209 193170 281.10
- Feeding..scans...      1     11754 198715 281.95
<none>                               186961 282.12
- Resting..scans...      1     21514 208474 283.39
- Group                  4    134539 321500 290.39

Step:  AIC=280.47
DPL ~ Group + Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans... + Locomotion..scans... + 
    Day.Length

                       Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
- Locomotion..scans...  1      5301 194462 279.30
- Day.Length            1      6066 195226 279.42
- Feeding..scans...     1     11503 200664 280.25
<none>                              189161 280.48
- Resting..scans...     1     22476 211636 281.84
- Group                 4    174836 363997 292.11

Step:  AIC=279.3
DPL ~ Group + Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans... + Day.Length

                    Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
- Day.Length         1      7166 201627 278.39
<none>                           194462 279.30
- Feeding..scans...  1     28025 222486 281.34
- Resting..scans...  1     38113 232575 282.67
- Group              4    193707 388168 292.04

Step:  AIC=278.39
DPL ~ Group + Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans...

                    Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
<none>                           201627 278.39
- Feeding..scans...  1     29741 231369 280.52
- Resting..scans...  1     43458 245085 282.25
- Group              4    205385 407012 291.46

Call:
lm(formula = DPL ~ Group + Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans...)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-142.670  -54.716   -0.963   56.879  182.432 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)        772.071    225.497   3.424  0.00232 **
GroupCON2          145.729     56.820   2.565  0.01732 * 
GroupCON3          -59.094     54.721  -1.080  0.29137   
GroupFRAG1          87.308     56.067   1.557  0.13308   
GroupFRAG2         173.771     59.459   2.923  0.00766 **
Feeding..scans...   -6.381      3.464  -1.842  0.07842 . 
Resting..scans...   -5.851      2.628  -2.227  0.03606 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 93.63 on 23 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.5517,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4348 
F-statistic: 4.718 on 6 and 23 DF,  p-value: 0.002873
```

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: NULL 
  Log-likelihood: -8.959541
  Fixed: DPL_log ~ Feeding..scans... + Resting..scans... + Locomotion..scans... +      Socialising..scans... 
          (Intercept)     Feeding..scans...     Resting..scans...  Locomotion..scans... 
          6.636760057          -0.012219304          -0.011172679           0.023186770 
Socialising..scans... 
         -0.003913746 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Habitat
         (Intercept)
StdDev: 1.480235e-05

 Formula: ~1 | Group %in% Habitat
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:   0.2189021 0.288025

Number of Observations: 30
Number of Groups: 
           Habitat Group %in% Habitat 
                 2                  5
```

How should I interpret these results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your output results?

Comment: Uploaded the outputs!